# final keyword in condition section of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements, final

A.

```
    int a=10,b=20;
    for(int i=0;a>b;i++)
    {
      System.out.print("aa");
    }
    System.out.print("bb");
```

B.

```
    final int a=10,b=20;
    for(int i=0;a>b;i++)
    { 
      System.out.print("aa");
    } 
    System.out.print("bb");
```

Q. why code A prints an output "bb" while code B returns an error "unreachable code"?

Comment: final variables can never be changed while runtime, but normal variables can. so in **A** there it is possible to reach the inside of the for loop, but in **B** its never possible

Comment: To clarify, in **A** it's *theoretically* possible to for it to enter the loop, if there were some additional code in between. In other words, the compiler won't try to guess the flow unless it's really obvious.

Comment: @ XtremeBaumer Both A and B the final variables are not changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
final int a=10,b=20;
```

means the variables will never Change its values after compiled

therefore this  for Loop

```
for(int i=0;a>b;i++)
```

has a never breaking condition (a>b will never be true), therefore the Loop is forever and this becomes

```
System.out.print("bb");
```

**"unreachable code"**

Answer (score 1):

On the Section A code can be changed like below and print both outputs. Note that while execute on the loop it's possible to change the value on a and b. and output will be **`aabb`**

```
    int a=10,b=20;
    for(a=30;a>b;)
    {
      System.out.print("aa");
      a=a-20;
    }
    System.out.print("bb");
```

In section B on the run time it's not possible to change the values of a or b since those are Final variable. Due to that reason JVM can identify that there is no possibility of **`a>b`** condition getting true. (Since a>b always false).

So JVM will throw compilation error saying Unreachable code.

Answer (score 1):

final key word says that a and b values cannot be changed i.e. they are values and not variables and therefore for loop will never execute inner statement, so the compiler deduces that the code inside for loop is unreachable.

Comment: in code B, try this: final int a=10,b=20; a = 25; this will give compilation error. So this means a and b are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

> B returns an error "unreachable code"

```
for(int i=0;a>b;i++) //with final modifier, `a` & `b` are constants
```

> How compiler sees your code with final modifier, that's compiler complains about

```
for(int i=0;10>20;i++)
```

> 10 will be always less than 20, so your body of loop in `unreachable code`